# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "А какими новыми, как бы заново появившимися на свет(,) увидели мы и село, и свою школу, и самих себя"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении после слова "на свет": А какими новыми, как бы заново появившимися на свет увидели мы и село, и свою школу, и самих себя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"За"** запятую следующие аргументы:

1. Пояснительные отношения. (Это не уточнение, потому что значения не от широкого к узкому, а равноправные,  причастный оборот поясняет подробности "нового").
2. Здесь есть признаки метафорического сравнения: село, школу и себя сравнивает с новорождённым.

**"Против"**:

Связь сочетания "появившимися на свет" осуществляется непосредственно с последующим глаголом-связкой. Между прилагательным и причастным оборотом возможно поставить **И**,  поэтому можем считать однородными составными именными сказуемыми - "увидели новыми, (и) как бы заново появившимися на свет.

Поэтому зависит от автора. Произнесёт с паузой и подчеркнёт пояснение и сравнение - запятая нужна. Прочитает без паузы, как однородные члены - не нужна.

Я бы не поставила.

Comment: Вы допускаете обособление именной части второго сказуемого? "Какими новыми, как бы заново появившимися на свет, увидели" - ведь это сказуемое?

Answer (score 3):

А какими новыми, как бы заново появившимися на свет увидели мы и село, и свою школу, и самих себя.

Ставится запятая (перед оборотом "как бы заново появившимися на свет"? - М_Г), обособления нет, это однородные члены.  Общий смысл однородных членов заключается в раскрытии одной общей темы новизны, при этом мы как бы подбираем ряд слов, помогающих эту тему выразить. Это не уточнение и н пояснение.

Примеры:

В ста шагах от мельницы находился маленький, со всех сторон открытый навес (однородные члены)

Он приобрел старую, датированную концом XVIII века, картину (уточнение, обособляется)

Дашу удивила доморощенность всего этого, так нашумевшего, дерзновения (пояснение, обособляется)

Кроме того, если оборот входит в сказуемое, как его вообще можно обособить? Например: Уставшими, но веселыми, пришли мы домой.

(Ответ исправлен).

Comment: Vera,Вы не вдумались.Речь о запятой ПОСЛЕ однородных членов, а она как раз НЕ СТАВИТСЯ, только МЕЖДУ.Речь о неоднородности не идёт. Другое дело, что пояснение здесь есть: новые - это какие? это как бы заново появившиеся на свет -и сравнение, и пояснение.

Comment: Я вижу, что исправлен, и прямо на противоположный, хоть бы в комментарии указали, почему так резко сменили мнение.Но и новое мнение очень категорично.Вы удивлённо вопрошаете: "Как можно обособить оборот, входящий в сказуемое".Можно, если придать ему пояснительный характер или превратить в сравнение(что здесь и имеет место)Кстати, в Вашем примере опечатка или что? "Уставшими, но веселыми, пришли мы домой". Вот здесь просто однородные члены, они соединены противительным союзом НО, запятой НЕТ.А вот здесь возможна: Весёлыми, как будто бы даже навеселе, пришли мы домой.

Comment: И вообще, я не поняла Ваш второй ответ. Был вопрос:"Нужна ли запятая в предложении после слова "на свет".."?. Вы отвечаете: "Ставится запятая, обособления нет". Как понять? Довольно противоречивое утверждение.Правда,потом объяснили, о чём речь,вновь с претензией на истину, но примеры привели совсем другие, на исходные непохожие.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы запятую поставил:

*А какими новыми, как бы заново появившимися на свет, увидели мы и село, и свою школу, и самих себя.*

.

А вот если бы не было ***"а какими"*** -- обошёлся бы, наверное, без запятой:

*Новыми, как бы заново появившимися на свет увидели мы и село, и свою школу, и самих себя.*

Answer (score 0):

Запятая закрывает причастный оборот. Почему не надо ставить? Даже если однородные члены, запятая нужна!

Comment: Серж, дорогой, ЭТОТ причастный оборот ВХОДИТ В СКАЗУЕМОЕ: "увидели заново появившимися на свет". Это не обособленное определение.

Comment: Людмила,в данном конкретном случае, он стоит перед сказуемым. Поэтому я говорю, что запятая нужна.

Comment: Вы смеётесь? Он НЕ ПЕРЕД, а ВХОДИТ в него, а ПЕРЕД обосабливается ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ ПЕРЕД СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫМ,которое определяет.